# Reboot corrupts files written to external storage of Galaxy S4 with FileChannel.map()

Tags: android, storage, mmap, galaxy, leveldb

I have the following problem:

Our Android app uses *LevelDB* to write files to the device's external storage. *LevelDB* internally uses `mmap` to write. Our problem so far only occurs on the *Samsung Galaxy S4*. Files are written to and read from the storage without any problem. But after a restart of the device, the file is corrupted.

Did anyone experience something similar?

I wrote a small demo app to check if `mmap` is the problem and in fact it seems to be. The demo app displays an image that ships with the app and a button below the image.
If the button is pressed

- the image is written to external storage using `FileChannel.map()` (as equivalent to `mmap`)
- the image is read from external storage and displayed below the button.

After the button was pushed once and the image was written to external storage, the app shows two copies of the image. This works even after restarting the app. After a reboot of the Galaxy S4 however, the file on external storage is corrupted and only the first image is shown.

Note: This problem doesn't occur when the file gets written using `FileOutputStream` and it only occurs on *Galaxy S4*.

It would be great if someone knows how to circumvent this problem using *LevelDB*.
To make it easier for you to reproduce the problem, here is some code of the demo app:

*main.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Original image as included in the app:" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Write image file to storage"
        android:onClick="writeFile" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Image as read from storage:" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/storageImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*StartActivity.java*

```java
package net.skoobe.StorageWrite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        retrieveImage();
    }

    public void writeFile(View v) {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // we can read and write the media

            try {

                // convert resource to Bitmap
                BitmapDrawable bm = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test_image));
                Bitmap b = bm.getBitmap();

                // store bitmap data in byte array
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                bos.close();

                File dir = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();

                // write bytes to external storage
                FileChannel readWriteChannel = new RandomAccessFile(dir.getPath() + "/test_image_s.png", "rw").getChannel();
                ByteBuffer readWriteBuf = readWriteChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, bitmapdata.length);
                readWriteBuf.put(bitmapdata);
                readWriteChannel.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("StorageWrite", e.toString());
            }

            retrieveImage();

        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            Log.e("StorageWrite", "storage not writable");
        } else {
            Log.e("StorageWrite", "storage neither writable nor readable");
        }
    }

    private void retrieveImage() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // we can read and write the media

            try {

                // create Drawable from PNG file on external storage
                File dir = getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
                String pathName = dir.getPath() + "/test_image_s.png";
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);

                // display the image
                ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storageImage)).setImageDrawable(d);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("StorageWrite", e.toString());
            }

        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            Log.e("StorageWrite", "storage not writable");
        } else {
            Log.e("StorageWrite", "storage neither writable nor readable");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my collegues found a solution to circumvent the problem on the S4. He realized that the external storage on this device is actually emulated. Internally, it uses the internal storage. So we can as well use the internal storage directly.

Fortunately - starting from API level 11 - there is an SDK call to find out whether or not the storage is emulated: [`isExternalStorageEmulated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageEmulated%28%29)

I think it's a clean solution as it is not targeted to a single device only. Whenever the external storage is emulated, just use the internal storage.

However we still think there is a Galaxy S4 specific problem with the emulated external storage if data is written via mmap(2).